# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoBulkWriteError:

Tags: mongodb, schema

I was writing a migration. I am taking an array of objects and I am adding each object as a document to ListingDestination collection using bulkwrite. I was generating ids for each object and then adding it as a document.ListingDestination is an empty collection.

```
import listingDestinations from '/common/info/listingDestinations';

Migrations.add({
    version: 329,
    name: 'Add ListingDestinations',
    async up() {
        const {default: ListingDestination} = require('/common/db/listingDestination');
        let destinations = [];
        for (var listingDestination of listingDestinations) {
            const _id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000000000);
            destinations.push(
                {
                    insertOne: {
                        'document': {
                            _id,
                            ...listingDestination,
                        },
                    },
                },
            );
            if (destinations.length) ListingDestination.rawCollection().bulkWrite(destinations);
        }
    },
});
```

But I am getting an error
**UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoBulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: settlin.listingDestinations index: *id* dup key: { _id: 6062257022015.0 }** even though i am generating random ids each time.

Comment: You don't need to create the id on your own, it will automatically be assigned. The function you are using will runs into collision if you have a longer list. (~5000000) If you insist to create the id on your own `crypto.randomUUID()` would be a better choice.

Comment: I did a small test by adding numbers into a set with your function **until** the size of the set doesn't change, and it usually terminates under 5000000 entries.